# How to get number of images in a slider and passing to next/previous function in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I [found this tutorial](http://onehungrymind.com/build-sweet-photo-slider-angularjs-animate/) on how to build a basic image slider in AngularJS. I have it working great in my own solution but I have come across one issue I am not sure how to solve.

In the tutorial, the image sources are being hardcoded into the `$scope` using `$scope.slides` which is defined in `app.js`. Unfortunately, this approach won't work for me because I am going to have multiple sliders which are populated dynamically based on JSON data.

The issue I am running into is that the next/previous functions of the slider rely on getting a count of the total number of images within the slider. In the example they are using `$scope.slides.length` to accomplish this. If I hardcode the number of images in the slider I've built, it works perfectly, but I would like to know how I can generate this number dynamically depending on the slides being populated.

Here's some code from my `app.js`:

```
$scope.direction = 'left';
$scope.currentIndex = 0;

$scope.setCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
    $scope.direction = (index > $scope.currentIndex) ? 'left' : 'right';
    $scope.currentIndex = index;
};

$scope.isCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
    return $scope.currentIndex === index;
};

$scope.prevSlide = function () {
    $scope.direction = 'left';
    $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex < $scope.slides.length - 1) ? ++$scope.currentIndex : 0;
    //$scope.slides.length should be dynamic
};

$scope.nextSlide = function () {
    $scope.direction = 'right';
    $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex > 0) ? --$scope.currentIndex : $scope.slides.length - 1;
    //$scope.slides.length should be dynamic
};
```

Here's my slider template:

```
<div class="slider">
    <img ng-repeat="slide in vm.selectedProduct.images" class="slide slide-animation nonDraggableImage" ng-swipe-right="nextSlide()" ng-swipe-left="prevSlide()" ng-hide="!isCurrentSlideIndex($index)" ng-src="{{slide.source}}">
    <a class="arrow prev" href="#" ng-click="nextSlide()"></a>
    <a class="arrow next" href="#" ng-click="prevSlide()"></a>
    <nav class="nav">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul class="dots">
                <li class="dot" ng-repeat="slide in slides">
                    <a href="#" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentSlideIndex($index)}" ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex($index);"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here's a working example of the slider using hardcoded values for `$scope.slides.length` (click a button and then click a link to see it)

## [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qs1Psw7ZMe8fxWNRjalJ)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the solution was so simple that it didn't even occur to me. `vm.selectedProduct.images.length` was all I needed. Didn't think that would work within `app.js` due to scope, but it worked perfectly!